# Beamer Singapore theme, customize navigation

Tags: beamer, titles, templates

I am using the Singapore theme for a beamer presentation, with
a custom color theme. I am trying to remove the fading of the navigation
bar and the navigation in the title page, but I cannot get either of these things to work.
Is there a standard option to do it? How can I remove the fading?

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image: screen shot of my beamer]

Here is a reproducible .tex:

```tex
\documentclass[french]{beamer}
% Color Scheme:
% https://github.com/jrnold/beamercolorthemesolarized

\usecolortheme[accent=blue]{solarized}
\usetheme{Singapore}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols} {
    \insertslidenavigationsymbol
    \insertframenavigationsymbol
    \insertsubsectionnavigationsymbol
    \insertsectionnavigationsymbol
    \insertdocnavigationsymbol
    \insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol
    \hspace{1em}
    \usebeamerfont{footline}
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\title{Title}
\author{My name}
\date{A Date}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\section{Previous}
\section{Next}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{A Frame}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to remove both the navigation buttons by resetting the `navigation symbols template` and the headline shading by changing the `headline` template.
Both modifications can be made locally inside the group formed by the `{...}` enclosing.
The second modification is made by the `\removeheadshading` macro, which is basically the same definition as the default template, without the shading defined inside `beamerthemeSingapore.sty`

See the full example below

```
% arara: lwpdflatex
\documentclass[french]{beamer}
% Color Scheme:
% https://github.com/jrnold/beamercolorthemesolarized

\usecolortheme[accent=blue]{solarized}
\usetheme{Singapore}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols} {
    \insertslidenavigationsymbol
    \insertframenavigationsymbol
    \insertsubsectionnavigationsymbol
    \insertsectionnavigationsymbol
    \insertdocnavigationsymbol
    \insertbackfindforwardnavigationsymbol
    \hspace{1em}
    \usebeamerfont{footline}
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}
\newcommand{\removeheadshading}[0]{%
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}{section in head/foot}%
        \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}%
}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\title{Title}
\author{My name}
\date{A Date}

\begin{document}

% Start group to make modifications local
{% 
% Remove navigation bar
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
% Remove the headline shading
\removeheadshading
% Typeset the actual titlepage
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
% End the local group
}

\section{Previous}
\section{Next}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{A Frame}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This removes the header; I would like the keep the header, but remove the gray fading background

Comment: @SamuelYvon I edited my answer to adress your comment

Comment: Thank you very much; this is exactly what I wanted. Learned a lot from your answer.

Comment: Once again, what is the reason for the downvote ?

Answer (score 1):

With the beamer [development version from github](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/e4f8639f03102ef5f8a75e93d64869d2ee3648e9) or beamer v3.70 (or newer), you can simply change the colour of the headline gradient for your title page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme[accent=blue]{solarized}
\usetheme{Singapore}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=background canvas.bg}
\frame{\titlepage}
}

\section{Previous}
\section{Next}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{A Frame}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]